# Trying to Join two select queries that make calls to temp tables

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

I'm trying to build a rather complex query that I keep getting stuck. I'm thinking that this is the best way to append my table with the subsequent columns. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 for compatibility reasons with the server I need to access.

This is similar to what I have:

```
SELECT
    FirstSet.PID
    ,FirstSet.PNAME
    ,FirstSet.PTYPE
    ,FirstSet.CONTACT_DATE
    ,FirstSet.P_Start_Time
    ,FirstSet.P_End_Time
    ,FirstSet.ShiftBlock
    ,SecondSet.NumEncCompleted
    ,SecondSet.NumEncScheduled
FROM
    (SELECT
         a.PID, a.PNAME, a.PTYPE,
         st.CONTACT_DATE,
         MIN(st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME) AS 'P_Start_Time',
         MAX(st.SLOT_END_TIME) AS 'P_End_Time',
         CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE , MIN(st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME) , MAX(st.SLOT_END_TIME)) AS NUMERIC(18 , 2)) / 60 AS 'HoursWorkedInDay',
         CASE 
            WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE , MIN(st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME) , DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, MAX(st.SLOT_END_TIME))) AS NUMERIC(18 , 2)) / 60 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
               THEN 1
            WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE , MIN(st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME) , DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, MAX(st.SLOT_END_TIME))) AS NUMERIC(18 , 2)) / 60 BETWEEN 5 AND 10 
               THEN 2
         WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE , MIN(st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME) , DATEADD(MINUTE , 30 , MAX(st.SLOT_END_TIME))) AS NUMERIC(18 , 2)) / 60 BETWEEN 10 AND     13 THEN 3
             ELSE NULL
        END AS 'ShiftBlock'
    FROM
        #SlotsTable st
    LEFT JOIN 
        #VisitsTable vt ON st.PID = vt.PID
    LEFT JOIN 
        #ARPB a ON st.CONTACT_DATE = a.SERVICE_DATE
            AND st.PID = a.PID
    WHERE
        st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME >= @Report_Start_Date
        AND st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME < @Report_End_Date
    GROUP BY
        st.CONTACT_DATE, a.PID, a.PNAME,
        a.PTYPE) AS FirstSet
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
    a.PID
   ,a.PNAME
   ,st.CONTACT_DATE
   ,vt.NumEncCompleted
   ,vt.NumEncScheduled
FROM
    #SlotsTable st
    LEFT JOIN #VisitsTable vt
    ON st.PID = vt.PID
    LEFT JOIN #ARPB a
    ON st.CONTACT_DATE = a.SERVICE_DATE
    AND st.PID = a.PID
WHERE
    st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME >= @Report_Start_Date
    AND st.SLOT_BEGIN_TIME < @Report_End_Date
GROUP BY
    a.PID
   ,a.PNAME
   ,st.CONTACT_DATE
   ,vt.NumEncCompleted
   ,vt.NumEncScheduled   
) 
AS SecondSet
ON FirstSet.PROV_ID = SecondSet.PROV_ID
ORDER FirstSet.PROV_ID
```

I think this is the approach I need to take, but right now I'm getting formatting errors.  Otherwise when I try to add in NumEncCompleted or NumEncScheduled into the Select query with the shift calculation I end up returning multiple results for each CONTACT_DATE seems to add in values for multiple PID as a single PID result. I have the following right before each temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb'..'#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide table definitions and some sample data (insert statements) that replicates the issue?

Comment: What *formatting errors* ? I think `SecondSet` doesn't seem to add any value. What is the purpose of `NumEncCompleted`, `NumEncScheduled` to join independently to the grouped result in FirstSet  + no aggregation ? This will end up with multiple rows with the `INNER JOIN` surely. I think I'm missing the expected outcome of this query/question..hmmm

Comment: Actually that formatting error was corrected by changing 'ORDER FirstSet.PROV_ID' to 'ORDER BY FirstSet.PROV_ID'.  Feel dumb for missing that.

Comment: So your problem is solved? Or are there other errors now that you are not getting the formatting error?

Comment: Solved now.  That was the only error.